# Why do my unittest work on Chrome driver, but not PhantomJS?

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver

I was writing my first unittest under the [Selenium Pychon Bindings document](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#using-selenium-to-write-tests).

I write the test using Chrome driver as below :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import unittest

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver")

    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(r"http://www.python.org")
        self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
        el = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        el.send_keys("pycon")
        el = driver.find_element_by_id("submit")
        el.click()
        assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Run it on terminal and it works.  Terminal returns:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 7.873s

OK
```

But if i replace

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver")
```

with

```
self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(r"C:\phantomjs-2.1.1\bin\phantomjs")
```

code as below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import unittest


class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(r"C:\phantomjs-2.1.1\bin\phantomjs")


    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(r"http://www.python.org")
        self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
        el = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        el.send_keys("pycon")
        el = driver.find_element_by_id("submit")
        el.click()
        assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

My terminal gives me an ERROR:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_search_in_python_org (__main__.PythonOrgSearch)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_python_org_search.py", line 24, in test_search_in_python_org
    el.click()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)    
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Element is not   
"Content-Length":"81","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:50294",   
67e-433b649e227d\"}","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click",    
elative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"",    
","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},    
46/click"}}
Screenshot: available via screen

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 6.214s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Could somebody please tell me why I cannot use `click` in PhantomJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with PhantomJS, screenshots are one of your most helpful debugging tools. I modified your script to record a screenshot at the point of failure:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import unittest


class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()


    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(r"http://www.python.org")
        self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
        el = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        el.send_keys("pycon")
        el = driver.find_element_by_id("submit")
        try:
            el.click()
        except:
            screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
            with open('screenshot.png', 'wb') as w:
                w.write(screenshot)
        assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

When I run it, I get [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4SBa.png).

You'll note that the page has rendered as if it was on a mobile browser. You should set the browser window size when working with phantomjs:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    self.driver.set_window_size(800, 1000)
```

Once you do that, and compare the chrome and phantom renderings, you'll see that phantom isn't loading in the submit button correctly:

[image: Chrome Vs Phantom rendering]

One work around would be to send the ENTER key, rather than click the button:

```
def test_search_in_python_org(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.set_window_size(800, 1000)
    driver.get(r"http://www.python.org")
    self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
    el = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
    el.send_keys("pycon")
    el.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
    with open('screenshot2.png', 'wb') as w:
        w.write(screenshot)
```

With the above code, I now see results:

[image]

It's worth noting that this is why many people, myself included, do not use PhantomJS for testing purposes. I find I am much better off using Chrome and/or Firefox, by either running them in their own headless modes, or by using a virtual frame buffer (like Xvfb).

I personally do my testing on cloud based linux instances, and I use [pyvirtualdisplay](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay) with [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) to manage my virtual displays. With both installed, pyvirtualdisplay will entirely manager your virtual display session. To use it with your above script, I would do the following:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.display = Display(visible=False, size=(1200, 1500))
        self.display.start()
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()


    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        # Do test

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()
        self.display.stop()
```

All that said, I have no experience with Windows, but I believe a similar configuration exists for that OS

Comment: thank you very much.  It seems I could remove PhantomJS from my computer.  Could you offer me some example, material or document about using Chrome in headless mode?

Comment: @PaichengWu I add some additional detail to the answer